# Issue with QrCode In Laravel, what the problem?

Tags: php, laravel

I use this Laravel package to insert a QrCode:

```
https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-php-simple-qr-codes-generate/
```

When i execute this route, i have my QrCode in a web page:

```
Route::get('qrcode', function () {
 return QrCode::size(300)
                 ->backgroundColor(255,55,0)
                 ->generate('A simple example of QR code');
 });
```

But what i need, is to insert the same QrCode in my blade, so i tried this code:

```
 <body>
{{ QrCode::size(300)->backgroundColor(255,55,0)->generate('A simple example of QR code')}}
 </body>
```

I'm not having a QrCode, but the **response** (SVG text)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
    {!! QrCode::size(300)->backgroundColor(255,55,0)->generate('test'); !!}
```